# Improve runtime of counting appearances with combinatorics

Tags: algorithm, haskell, runtime, combinatorics

I want to count how many d digit numbers does not include the number 9, and since it can be big, output it modulo 10^9 + 7.

Im running the following code t times, on up to 10^18 digit numbers, which I guess the solve function should take care of easily, right? So then it is perhaps the reading or printing that takes a lot of time.

Any tips how to speed this up?

```
main = do
    contents <- getContents
    let (t:ds) = (map read . words) contents
    let ans = map solve ds
    sequence_ (map print ans)

solve :: Integer -> Integer
solve ds = mod (8 * 9^(ds - 1)) (10^9 + 7)
```

Comment: Is this project Euler? That's not a problem :) only asking.

Comment: Kattis:) https://open.kattis.com/problems/nine

Comment: I have a strange feeling like using base 9 instead of base 10 might be a way to start...

Comment: Yes. @Redu is absolutely right. It is NOT a SW problem, it is an arithmetical problem. N=9^d. That is all. BTW, not NUMBER  9? but DIGIT 9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what the site wants to see, is that you grasp the concept of *modulo over multiplication*. It holds that:

```
(a * b) mod c == ((a mod c) * (b mod c)) mod c
```

Furthermore they did not choose `10^9+7` *arbitrarily*: it is - as far as I know - a huge prime number than can be represented by an 32-bit integer. As a result we can do **all calculus with `Int32`**, which is faster than working with `Integer` (that has arbitrary precision).

## Multiplication approach (less efficient)

As a result, we can make our own `mulmod` function:

```
mulmod :: Int32 -> Int32 -> Int32 -> Int32
mulmod m a b = mod (a*b) m
```

Now we can calculate the number modulo `m` with:

```
solvemod :: Int32 -> Int -> Int32
solvemod m d = foldl (mulmod m) 8 (replicate (d-1) 9)
```

And then the problem can be solved with:

```
solve :: Int -> Int32
solve = solvemod (10^9+7)
```

For the given sample input it results in:

```
Prelude> solve 1
8
Prelude> solve 2
72
Prelude> solve 100
343393926
```

Which is - according to the website - correct.

## Power approach

Nevertheless it is still inefficient. We can define a `powmod` like:

```
powmod :: Integral i => Int64 -> Int64 -> i -> Int64
powmod m = powmod'
    where powmod' _ 0 = 1
          powmod' a i | even i = rec
                      | otherwise = mod (a*rec) m
              where rec = powmod' (mod (a*a) m) (div i 2)
```

Then the `solve` mechanism is:

```
solve :: Integral i => i -> Int64
solve d = mod (8 * powmod m 9 (d-1)) m
    where m = 10^9+7
```

Again resulting in:

```
*Main> solve 1
8
*Main> solve 2
72
*Main> solve 100
343393926
*Main> solve (10^18)
303706813
```

The last query took only a few milliseconds, so I guess this is efficient enough. I submitted the last approach to Kattis, and got:

> 15:29:31 "I Hate The Number Nine"    Accepted    0.01 s  Haskell

So it took only 0.01s to calculate the testcases.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the great answer. I learned a lot of new things

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is simply an arithmetic problem which can easily be handled in base 9 since we will drop only one number character. If you don't want to use  2 number characters such as I don't want 9 and 4 then you shall go with base 8. So my solution would be;

```
solve :: Int -> Integer
solve n = (8*9^(n-1)) `mod` (10^9 + 7)

*Main> solve 1
8
*Main> solve 2
72
*Main> solve 100
343393926
```